# Labview using .net list type with 3rd party dll

Tags: .net, labview, publickeytoken

I'm trying to use Labview to control and obtain data from a camera using a .net assembly provided by the camera developer. It's mostly going well, with Labview managing to use each of the classes and methods correctly, except for those that require a `System.Collections.Generic.List` of one of the classes in the .net assembly.

Whenever I try to create a list with the desired contents of the list, I get the error:

> "PublicKeyToken cannot be null"

And I have noted that the version of the dll, as reported by labview changes between *1.1.0.0* and *0.0.0.0*.

I have tried to determine what the public key token is for the dll, and I have not been able to determine what it is.

I must be missing something?

Comment: What is the camera you are using and can you provide a link to the dll documentation?

Comment: The camera is one of the cameras listed as compatible with [link](https://api.ricoh/docs/camera-usb-sdk-dotnet/) . You will need to sign up on that website if you want to download the sdk.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new List<T>? I don't think you could create a new one in LabVIEW, because there is no concept of generics in LV.  If it accepts an IEnumerable<T> you might be able to make a LabVIEW array of the objects, and then use to To .Net Object VI on the array.